# Is it possible to rekey an Andersen exterior door with Kwikset SmartKey?

Tags: lock

I want to use the Kevo lock on my front door and have my back doors have the same physical key (even though they clearly will not have electronic keying).

To do this, I need to replace the cylinder on my Andersen doors with something that is compatible with Kwikset SmartKey -- either a SmartKey cylinder if possible, for "higher" security, or a standard Kwikset cylinder that the SmartKey locks can learn.

I can't find any information on what cores, etc, are compatible with Andersen doors or where to source them.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you want - is there something non-standard about the Anderson doors that means you can't put a standard lockset in them? Have you talked to a locksmith?

Comment: @MichaelKohne Yes, Andersen doors do not take a deadbolt. They use their own locking mechanism and you just replace the cylinder with the particular type you need.

Comment: I can find anything on Andersen locks or doors; just a reseller, window company, or locksmith in Florida. The Kwikset SmartKey is scary easy to break so I'd advise to replace the cylinder of the Kevo with a bump resistant non-SmartKey. Kwikset residential locks, including the SmartKey, use a 66 key so that may help your searches. Most locksmiths as well as big box hardware stores will rekey any/all items you purchased there for free, something to consider when comparing prices to online.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sR-h64WwfW8&feature=youtu.be&t=1m53s

Comment: @Jason You can replace the cylinder on the Kevo with something more secure? What sort of cylinder type am I looking for?

Comment: "bump resistant non-SmartKey"

Comment: @Jason No, I mean literally what type of cylinder do I need; I am assuming that every cylinder in the world will not fit into this one deadbolt...

Comment: Kwikset makes some, the locking mechanism of the Kevo is standard it just has the added electronics and servo on top of it.

Comment: My Andersen rear door uses a standard screen door cylinder.  Take yours apart and upload a photo!

Comment: @Jason I have disassembled the Kevo lock now, and it doesn't seem to have a standard cylinder.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer I got a pre-release version and an off the shelf version and they both have the same 5 pin cylinder as the residential Kwikset deadbolt I've had for years and a new one from the shelf. I don't know what you're missing on it.

Comment: @Jason Are you confusing the cylinder with the lock core? Also, I'm still really unsure what you think I will accomplish by swapping one insecure Kwikset lock core for another insecure Kwikset lock core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question: It is almost certainly possible to get a replacement cylinder for your Andersen door which accepts the Kwikset keyway, and have it keyed to accept the same key you're now using on the front door... or reset the front door to respond to the key the new cylinder ships with. My storm door uses a Euro-style cylinder, which is uncommon in the US but a good locksmith ought to be able to handle this request.

As others have said, though, I'd replace the SmartKey cylinder while you're at it. They were a nice idea, but they really have proven to be less secure than I'm comfortable with. A replacement cylinder should be cheap, and rekeying it doesn't add that much cost.

Comment: Highly bumpable in a different way than most locks are bumped. It involves the magic rekey mechanism releasing under attack, allowing the tumbler to be turned. Not-So-Smartkey...

Comment: Didn't see a need to spell out the details. "They're vulnerable and worth replacing" is good enough for most folks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Kevo lock doesn't support rekeying. The cylinder is fixed, not removable. Thanks though! In the end, I went with a Baldwin electronic lock that took a standard cylinder, and then replaced it and the patio doors with Mul-T-Lock cylinders.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer -- good choice on the Mul-T-Locks, even their low security stuff is going to be a fair slight trickier than an average Kwikset-klone from the big box store, and their top-of-the-line stuff, while not the ultimate in high security, takes quite a bit of skill to attack.